# Show only pages you are author of

Tags: theme-development, loop, pages, user-roles

I am trying to only show pages that a user is the author of for any role other than administrator. The code below seems to put the site in an infinite loop and it ultimately dies.

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() 
{
    global $typenow;
    
    if( 'page' !== $typenow )
        return;
    
    if( current_user_can('add_users') )
        return;
    
    if( !isset( $_GET['post_status'] ) && !isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url('edit.php?author_name=joe&post_type=page') );
        exit();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To show only pages that a user is the author, I use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action to alter the query.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $wp_query ) { 
    
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    global $pagenow;

    if ( !empty($user->roles) ) {

        // BackEnd AND Entity "Page" AND "any role other than administrator" AND not New post
        if ( is_admin() && 'page' == $wp_query->query['post_type'] && !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) && !in_array($pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'author', $user->ID );
            add_filter( 'views_edit-page', '__return_empty_array' ); // To hide filters in top of the list page ( All(X) | Publish(X) | Draft(X) )
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Applying this code though shows no pages at all even though there should be one.

Comment: We are talking about the `wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page` page?

Comment: That's correct, but it seems like it needs the author name in it to show only 'mine' ? `edit.php?author_name=joe&post_type=page`